# Can't get the Today() function to work properly in MS Access 2016 Custom Web App

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to setup a query that will show me all of the records in a particular table where the listed expiry date is either in the past or upcoming in the next 6 months (approximately).

At the moment, I have the "Expiry" field added to my query and the 'Criteria' as .

When I try to save the query, I get the following message:

> Access can't evaluate an expression or convert data because data types aren't compatible with each other.
>
> TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Correlation ID: ae68949d-3041-3000-0984-71635f8fd670
>
> Date and Time: 7/28/2016 6:54:34 PM

I've tried searching the web for a solution, but most websites refer to the Date() function that doesn't seem to be available in the Access 2016 Custom Web App. When I take out the "+180", it works fine but obviously doesn't give me what I need.

Any help would be appreciated.

=============================

UPDATE:
Some users have asked for my SQL and Table Design details. I don't seem to have any way of accessing the SQL View (the option doesn't appear), but here's a copy of my table view:
[Access Query Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVh5i.jpg)

In the table, 'Active' is a Yes/No field and 'Expiry' is Date/Time.

Comment: Your query SQL isn't shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
< DateAdd(Day, 180, Today())
```

as criteria.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249452.aspx this should work in a custom web app.

Answer (score 0):

Error says that you have two different date types and they can't be compared. so, as the Today() returns only the Date with 12:00 pm, I can guess that your other "Expiry" Field is a datetime type. So,  you can do either: use Format function to convert datetime to date like this

`Format([2/22/2012 12:00 PM],"dd/mm/yyyy")`

or use Now() function which returns datetime,

or Share your Code :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the Now() function, but I get the same error message. In terms of the SQL, I'm not sure how to display it (I'm fairly new to Access, sorry). Can you give me any advice on how to access it?

Comment: just go to "SQL View" of the query and show us how the query looks like, also it will be helpful if you share the table design to see what datatypes are your query fields, after that it will be easy for the stackoverflow crowd to help you

Comment: Hi Tedo - I don't seem to have the SQL view. When I click the View drop-down, I only see 'Datasheet View' or 'Design View'. If I right click in the empty design space, the 'Query Type' and 'SQL Specific' menu options are greyed out. Is it something to do with using the Custom Web App feature?

Comment: I've updated my original post with the table design details